# How to get for jQuery ID from session PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have in session PHP:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = 2;
```

how can i get this for jQuery?

```
<script>
   var sessionid = ??? ;
   alert(sessionid);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it as the ID of an element (like the HTML element) if you want to access it from a script:

```
<html id="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
```

In the external script:

```
var sessionid = $('html').attr('id');
alert (sessionid);
```

This has the added benefit of being able to be read by an external script.

EDIT:

You would need to set the session before you output anything, so the full code would be something like:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['id']))
    $_SESSION['id'] = 'session1';
?><html id="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']?>">
  <head>
    <title>SESSION ID TEST</title>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        var sessionid = $('html').attr('id');
        alert (sessionid);
      })
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
   var sessionid = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>" ;
   alert(sessionid);
</script>
```

don't forget to call `session_start();`

Answer (score 2):

javascript executes on the client, which has no knowledge of a session id natively. You'll have to echo out the session id to assign the value to a javascript variable:

```
var sessionid = "<? echo $_SESSION['id']?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about..

```
<script>
 var sessionid = "<? echo $_SESSION['id']?>";
 alert(sessionid);
</script>
```